# Prove that the conic $x^2 - 4xy + y^2 -2x -20y -11 = 0$ is a hyperbola and find the centre $(h,k)$

Tags: conic-sections

> I have to prove that the conic $$x^2 - 4xy + y^2 -2x -20y -11 = 0$$ is a hyperbola and find the centre $(h,k)$.

I proved it is a hyperbola using discriminant $b^2-4ac $ and the answer was greater than zero hence a hyperbola. 
But I cannot seem to change the equation into the form 
$(x-h)^2/a^2 - (y-k)^2/b^2=1$ so as to find the centre...[image]

I could finally solve it with everyone's Help

Answer (score 2):

Let the linear terms vanish in

$$(x+h)^2-4(x+h)(y+k)+(y+k)^2-2(x+h)-20(y+k)-11.$$

By identification,

$$\begin{cases}2h-4k-2=0,\\2k-4h-20=0.\end{cases}$$

Solve for $(h,k)$ and you have the center.

Comment: A valuable hint (+1).

Answer (score 1):

Write first the terms containing $x$ as the beginning of the square of an affine function in $x$ and $y$:
$$x^2-4xy-2x= (x-2y-1)^2-(4y+4y^2+1),$$
so that the equation becomes
\begin{align}
x^2 - 4xy + y^2 -2x -20y -11 &=  (x-2y-1)^2-(4y+4y^2+1)+y^2-20y-11 \\
&= (x-2y-1)^2-3(y^2+8y+4)\\
&=  (x-2y-1)^2-3\bigl((y+4)^2-16\bigr).
\end{align}
Can you end the calculations?

Comment: I was trying to solve it like this trying to convert into hyperbola equation ... (x - y)^2 -x^2 + (x-1)^2 - 1 + y^2  (y-10)^2 -100 -11= 0